# oh my zsh's plugin "osx" not work

Tags: macos, plugins, oh-my-zsh

As the title,my oh my zsh has installed autojump plugin by homebrew,but osx doesn't work,I have open the plugin named osx in the .zshrc file.eg: plugins=(osx zsh-syntax-highlighting git autojump),and the file names ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/osx/os.plugin.zsh is correct.

I use the following command feedbacked a error "zsh: command not found: quick-look".

```
$ quick-look xx.jpg
```

I don't know why?Could somebody give me some help?Thx.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

`$ qlmanage -p xx.png`

`quick-look` is a function implemented inside the osx plugin that is actually calling the `qlmanage` command, if the above command works for you, just create an alias in your `~/.zshrc` to your convenient, some like this:

Creating the alias:

`$ echo "alias 'quick-look=qlmanage -p' >> ~/.zshrc`

Load the new changes to your current session:

`source ~/.zshrc`

Then you should be able to run:

`quick-look xx.png`